# Не отображается Full image

Tags: java, android

Делаю приложение с обоями, НО возникла проблема с отображением картинки, картинка появляется только после того как я нажимаю на кнопку "Установить обои"

Буду признателен за помощь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**мой код**

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

    public ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);
    }

    public void tempbitMap(View view){
        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]));
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        Bitmap tempbitMap = (BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]));
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempbitMap, width, height, true);
        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(FullImageActivity.this);
        wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
        wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
        try {
            wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы не вызываете ваш метод `tempbitMap` в `onCreate` методе. Сам по себе он не вызовется

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не получается у меня вызвать его ((

Comment: Как так. Не верю. Не может такого быть

Comment: я имею ввиду что конкретно я его не могу вызвать

Comment: Но вы хоть пытались?

Comment: пытаюсь так 

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);
        tempbitMap();

    }

        public void tempbitMap(){

И еще много как пытался, то критует приложение, то фулл картинка не показывается

Comment: Почему вы это в вопросе не пишете? Почему нужно несколько часов чтобы эту информацию от вас получить? Сколько часов у вас займёт добавление этой инфы в вопрос вместе с логами ошибки и указанием строки возникновения?

Comment: У вас же наверняка какая-то банальщина типа NPE, коя решается за секунд 20. Но пока вы не дадите нужной инфы мы не сможем вам сказать в какое место надо добавить пару символов чтобы всё заработало.

Comment: Все сделал))) Спасибо большое за помощь

Сделал так 

tempbitMap(null);
    }

        public void tempbitMap(View v){

Comment: Если б вы не назначали слушатели нажатий в разметке то этой проблемы бы вообще не возникло

Comment: дак я учусь, учусь, читаю.

без Вашей помощи вообще бы ничего не вышло